# First page of my website doesn't load correctly "css"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have a problem with my website using C# and .Net.
When i try to access to my website the first page doesn't load correctly because of the css which is the authentication page.
But after the connection, the website work perfectly by miracle and the css load correctly...
Is any one can help me please with this i would be very grateful.

Comment: This is very little information to go by... Do you use firebug? If so, do you see any errors inyour console or network tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem.  I'm assuming you're using Forms Authentication, right?

Your login page has a reference to your css file.  Let's say your css file is at /css/site.css.  When a user isn't authenticated, then their browser is denied access to the css file that your login page needs to render properly.

You need to configure your website to allow unauthenticated access to that path of your application.  In your web.config, add the following inside your <configuration> tag.

```
  <location path="css/site.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan that was the problem

Comment: I have another question please Ryan. I use more than 1 file of css how can i proceed

Comment: Just change the path to path="css" instead of path="css/[filenamehere]".  This will give unauthenticated (anonymous) users access to everything in the css directory.

Comment: If your css files are in different directories, then you can add as many of those <location> elements as you need under the <configuration> element.

Comment: I used 3 <location> elements... Thank you so much Ryan good evening

Answer (score 1):

This is bacause the CSS file needs authtication but at the stage of login page, the authentication is not yet available.

You need to allow unauthenticated access to the css file.
Add the following into the "" tag inside web.config file.

```
<location path="Path/file.ext">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```